# Show that $\{(x, y) \in V \times V | x, y \text{ are linearly dependent}\}$ is not a submanifold of the vector space $V\times V$

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector space, where $n \geq 2$,
and define
$$L := \{(x, y) \in V \times V : x, y \text{ are linearly dependent}\}.$$
What is meant by a "submanifold" in this context is a regular submanifold, defined this way:

A subset $S$ of a smooth $n$-manifold $M$ is called a regular submanifold of dimension $k$ if every point $p\in S$ is in the domain of a chart $(U,\mathrm{x})$ that has the following regular submanifold property with respect to $S$: $$\mathrm{x}(U\cap S)=\mathrm{x}(U)\cap(\mathbb{R}^k\times\{0\}).$$

The first task is to show that $L' := L \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$ is a submanifold of $V \times V$ and to compute the dimension of $L'$. I do this by defining appropriate charts, namely $(U,\mathrm{x})$ and $(V,\mathrm{y})$, where $$U=\{(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_{2n}):u_1\neq0\}$$ and
$$V=\{(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_{2n}):u_{n+1}\neq0\},$$
and $\mathrm{x}$ and $\mathrm{y}$ is given by
$$(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n,v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)\mapsto\left(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n,\frac{v_1}{u_1},\frac{v_1}{u_1}u_2-v_2,\frac{v_1}{u_1}u_3-v_3,\ldots,\frac{v_1}{u_1}u_n-v_n\right)$$ and
$$(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n,v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)\mapsto\left(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n,\frac{u_1}{v_1},\frac{u_1}{v_1}v_2-u_2,\frac{u_1}{v_1}v_3-u_3,\ldots,\frac{u_1}{v_1}v_n-u_n\right)$$ respectively.

The next task is to show that $L$ is not a submanifold. I guess I should assume that it is and show that this leads to a contradiction because of something at $(0,0)$, but how should I go on to do that?

Comment: Do you have any idea of why $(0, 0)$ is a "bad" point? I think it probably has something to do with dimension: you should check the dimension of the manifold $L \setminus (0, 0)$, and compare it to the dimension of the tangent space of $L$ at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: @Joppy I think I see. At $(0,0)$ we can move in all directions and still be inside of $L$, so the dimension of the tangent space there would be $2n$?

Comment: I don't think you can move in _all_ directions, since for example if $u, v \in V$ are independent, you can't move along a path $p(t) = (tu, tv)$, in the sense that this isn't really tangent to your space. However, you should be able to find $2n$ linearly independent tangent vectors at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: @Joppy Yes, that was a sloppy formulation. I meant to say that you can move along any of the $2n$ basis vectors, one at a time. Thank you for the help.